Jetty timeout idle session?
I am using http4k with Jetty.
I'have a quite long backend process which terminates correctly but the http connection is closed after some time.
I suspect that there is some timeout in Jetty.
My code is something like this:
    return ServerFilters.CatchAll()
        .then(DebuggingFilters.PrintRequestAndResponse())
        .then(appHttpHandler(env, RequestParser(printRequestForDebug), RequestSanitizer()))
        .asServer(
            Jetty(SERVICE_PORT(env))
        )

as you can see I don't use any particular configuration so I get all defaults.
Does this timeout exist?
If so how can I raise it?
Thanks a lot

Never mind there was a timeout at load balancer level. Leave this question hoping it could be of any help for other readers in the future ..
